# How to handle mapping of a foreign key of a table to multiple tables primary key?

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, jpa, jpa-2.0

I have 3 tables :

MainTable , Dependent1 , Dependent2.

MainTable foreign key (DependentPK ) is primary key of Table Dependent1 and Dependent1.
There is one to one Relation from MainTable to Dependent1 and MainTable to Dependent2.

MainTable :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "mainTable")
@Getter
@Setter
public class MainTable implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO_INCREMENT)
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    private Integer id;

    @Embedded
    DependentPK key;

    @Column(name = "mainfield1")
    private Integer mainField1;
}
```

DependentPK (Primary Key) :

```
@Embeddable
@EqualsAndHashCode
@Getter
@Setter
public class DependentPK implements Serializable {

    public DependentPK() {}


    public DependentPK(String field1, String field2) {
        this.field1 = field1;
        this.field2 = field2;
    }


    @Column(name = "field1", nullable = false)
    private String field1;

    @Column(name = "field1", nullable = false)
    private String field1;
}
```

Dependent1 Table :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "dependent1")
@Getter
@Setter
public class Dependent1 implements Serializable {

    @EmbeddedId
    private DependentPK id;

    @Column(name = "modified_by")
    private String modifiedBy;

}
```

Dependent2 Table :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "dependent2")
@Getter
@Setter
public class Dependent2 implements Serializable {

    @EmbeddedId
    private DependentPK id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

}
```

Above example is just for describing the problem.
I cannot change DB constraints and tables because it is production DB.

My Question is how to use one to one mapping annotation in this case?
   Because same composite key (combination of 2 columns) as foreign key referencing to Dependent1 and Dependent2 table primary key.

Answer (score 0):

You can only define a relationship between two entities, not between an entity and a primary key.

Knowing that, there are two main approaches to solve your problem:

1. Have a relationship with both `Dependent1` and `Dependent2` in your `MainTable`:

```java
@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "dependent1_id")
private Dependent1 dependent1;

@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "dependent2_id")
private Dependent2 dependent2;
```

2. If you are only ever going to need to have either `Dependent1` or `Dependent2` then you should consider using some kind of [inheritance for entities](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Inheritance). Then you would have a single relationship with a `DependentParent` and both `Dependent1` and `Dependent2` would inherit from it.

Comment: your 1st approach is not working and I don't want to go with your 2nd approach.

Comment: True. I forgot that you have a composite PK. In that case you would need to use `@JoinColumns` instead of `@JoinColumn`. Refer to [a nice example in the hibernate docs](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#d0e4865)